# List Wordpress.org Blog on Wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I have [a self-hosted blog](http://www.jonathonmoore.com/blog) at `www.MyPersonalSite.com/blog` that runs on the Wordpress.org platform. My buddy has a blog at `www.HisName.wordpress.com`.

He seems to get a lot more traffic to his blog. My inclination is that when he makes a post, it submits it to some central Wordpress blogroll. Is this right?

**Question:** Is there a way for me to list my blog such that it gets more exposure and people can search for it through Wordpress.com and subscribe to my posts?

Comment: Please direct wordpress.com questions to [wordpress.com support](http://en.support.wordpress.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only potentially WordPress specific (in the context of this site) part of this question seems to me to be about adding an update service to the list used by WordPress.

If you are correct that `wordpress.com` sites submit to a particular blogroll, and if `wordpress.com` allows outside sites to submit, then you can tell your site to submit to their list by going to `wp-admin->Settings->Writing` and then scroll to the bottom to find "Update Services" and add the list address. The rest needs to come from [wordpress.com support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, [Jetpack's Enhanced Distribution](http://jetpack.me/) is the closest you can get.

> Jetpack will automatically take the great published content from your blog or website and share it instantly with third party services like search engines, increasing your reach and traffic.

Just in case you don't know about Jetpack, it's a plugin by Automattic (the people behind WordPress) that brings WordPress.com's features to self-hosted WordPress blogs. So, I am guessing Jetpack's Enhanced Distribution is just what you need.